# Remote Execution platform

Tags: azure, ansible, salt-stack, octopus-deploy, remote-execution

I’m looking for a framework/platform that would allow me to execute remote commands on a Windows machine and report back the results. 
These machines would be public outside our company network, probably behind firewalls, proxies, etc. We have complete access over them and can configure them in any way we want. Think ATMs with 3G network.

I guess what i’m looking is something like SaltStack remote execution. But that enterprise plan has a hight cost per minion, and I need to install it on the thousands.

Another possible solution would be something like Octopus Deploy, Azure DevOps or any CD tool for that matter but without the need for environments.

I’ve looked also at ansible, but without an agent to overcome the target being behind firewalls, routers, proxies, I’m not sure how the reverse connection would work.

I would like to avoid Puppet or Chef for now. Ideally a cloud based solution would be wonderful, especially in azure.

Any recommends, directions?

Answer (score 0):

Octopus Deploy is currently working on "Ops Processes" which sounds like it might fit what you are looking for. It's on our [roadmap](https://octopus.com/company/roadmap) if you are interested, and we are planning to have the first round of features from this ready to ship in the next 8 weeks or so.

Caveat: I work at Octopus so read into that what you will

Comment: Sounds good but can I install the tentacle on 5K PCs? without cost?

Comment: Hi @Zapacila - 5k targets is definitely possible with Octopus, however there is a cost involved (we are a business after all). https://octopus.com/pricing for details

Comment: I understand, but the ocotopus business model does not fit this situation very well, as-in the price is per tentacle which usually are servers/vms, having it on 5K PCs which may increase to 10K in the next 2-3 years, most definetly unsustainable